# Powershell function creation with Set-Item and GetNewClosure

Tags: powershell, scriptblock

I am attempting to build a function that can itself create functions through the Set-Item command where I pass a scriptblock for the new function to the -Value parameter of Set-Item.  I'm running into an issue where using GetNewClosure on the scriptblock doesn't seem to be working and I just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the code below, first I'm creating a function manually (testFunc) which works as intended, in that setting $x to 2 after the function creation will not cause the function to return 2; instead it returns 1 because that was the value of $x at the time the function was created.  But when I try to do the same through the make-function function, the behavior changes.

I'm sure I'm overlooking something small.

```
> $x = 1
> $block = {$x}.GetNewClosure()
> Set-Item function:global:testFunc -Value $block
> testFunc
1 

> $x = 2
> testFunc
1 # still 1 because of GetNewClosure - this is expected behavior

> $x = 1
> function make-function { $block2 = {$x}.GetNewClosure()
       Set-Item function:global:testFunc2 -Value $block2
  }
> make-function
> testFunc2
1 

> $x = 2
> testFunc2
2 # Why is it not returning 1 in this case?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The clue is in the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure(v=vs.85).aspx) but it is subtle:

> Any local variables that are in the context of the caller are copied
>   into the module.

`GetNewClosure()` appears to capture "only" local variables i.e those from the caller's current scope.  So try this:

```
function Make-Function {
   $x = $global:x
   $function:global:testFunc2 = {$x}.GetNewClosure()
}
```

BTW you can see what variables are captured by `GetNewClosure()` into the newly created dynamic module by executing:

```
$m = (Get-Command testFunc2).Module
& $m Get-Variable -Scope 0
```

Comment: Awesome Keith!  Thanks for the help.  Your last piece of advice (i.e. getting the variables captured by GetNewClosure()) is really, really helpful.

Comment: How does one remove those functions that were created as function:global: ? I can't do it using remove-item, clear-item. Any ideas?